# Node.js Path infinity loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I have the following two files in a folder:

[image]

plus one file in same folder called `minions_model`

But when i try to call murder_model with:

```
var murder_model = require('./murder_model.js');
```

and call it to see its functions, i get:

```
{}
```

while i should see something like:

```
{ xxx: [Function: xxx] }
```

Update:
It seems like missionModel fails  to get murder file because of minionModel.

I noticed if i removed minionModel reference from Murder file, it would work.
But minionModel crashes because of Mission_model. so if i remove minionModel from MissionModel it would work. But its an infinity Loop!.

What causes this and how can i fix it?

Source:

minions:

```
var path = require('path');
var missionsCompålicated = require('./mission_model.js');


var mongoose = require('mongoose');
function yyy() {
    console.log("inside minions");
    return  499;
}

module.exports = {
    yyy : yyy,
};
```

Murder:

```
var path = require('path');

var MinionModel = require('./minions_model.js');

function xxx() {
    console.log("inside murder model");
}





module.exports = {
    /*botAttack : botAttack,*/
    xxx : xxx,
};
```

mission:

```
var xau = require('./murder_model.js');

    function getMission(userid) {

        console.log("??:)");
        console.log(xau);
        console.log(xau.xxx());
    }

module.exports = {
    getMission : getMission,

};
```

Its weird, because if i call it anywhere else ( not in minion,murder or mission, for example server.js it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are replacing the entire `module.exports` object and the two modules are requiring each other and causing a cyclic dependency. You can solve it my not replacing the `module.exports` object.

Try this :

```
module.exports.getMission = getMission;

module.exports.xxx = xxx;

module.exports.yyy = yyy;
```

Comment: Its weird, because if i call it anywhere else ( not in minion,murder or mission, for example server.js it works perfectly.